# Saving sent emails in Outlook 2010 not working for Pop3

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, pop3

I am using Outlook 2010 for my gmail emails which use IMAP I can set the system to store sent emails in the appropriate sent folder.  For another account which uses POP3 I can't configure outlook to save sent emails in the sent items folder.   the options seem to be diferent for IMAP and POP3 -  Is there anything I can do about this other than manually savings emsils every time I send them?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that if you have a POP3 account you will need to choose the option Deliver Messages to  as 'New Outlook Data file'.

Create the account :

- Add new Account> Auto Account Setup (Manually Configure Server Settings or additional Server types> Internet Email> Internet Email settings
- If you have a POP3 account choose the option Deliver Messages to: 'New Outlook Data file'.

If you choose the option 'Existing Outlook data file' for Deliver Messages to and choose an existing .pst file the sent messages do not get saved in the Sent folder. I deleted the account and set up a new account with the same configuration but put the Deliver Messages to  as 'New Outlook Data file'.

It created a new outlook file and saved sent items to the sent folder in the new .pst file which is by default created under you user profile in C:

Note that the option for 'Deliver Messages to' is visible only while creating the POP3 account. Once the account is created the option goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Pop3 works only for downloading emails, not for managing folders.

Answer (score 0):

The Sent Items folder will be different for the IMAP account than for the POP3 account.  When Outlook saves a sent email for IMAP, it is copied to the IMAP Sent Items folder back in your gmail account.

POP3 has no concept of folders, so any Sent Items will be stored in your Personal Folders in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just added a rule in Outlook that all messages `FROM` my email address will be moved to the Sent folder. Worked for me.